# How to import relative module from __main__ in python

Tags: python

I have two file

```
foo.py
main.py
```

while executing `python main.py`, I want `main.py` to import `foo.py`.

I tried

```
from . import foo
```

But python complains

```
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I also tried

```
from foo import func_name
```

It works, but that means I can only directly import what get exposed. I want to use it like `foo.func_name`

Is it possible to import the whole module in a relative way (regardless what the current working directory is)?

Comment: simply use  `import foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script directory is already a part of the import path. Simply use

```
import foo
```